# jack-admin: command not found under "prebuilts/sdk/tools" directory

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS to compile android-12.0.0_r21 on a VM inside windows with 14GB of RAM assigned. Android keeps failing to build due to "out of memory errors".

When I want to set JACK_SERVER_VM_ARGUMENTS, I cannot find jack-admin under "prebuilts/sdk/tools" directory of AOSP.

And repo shows "repo sync has finished successfully".

[Please see this link of "prebuilts/sdk/tools" directory, not found jack-admin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJxk4.png)

Answer (score 2):

After Android10, it should set: export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx4096m". The build requires 16Gb of RAM/swap, and this could solve the issue that out of memory.